# Django: submit only one form created with for loop

Tags: python, django

In my code I'm using a class CreateView with a ListView. I'm also using a for loop to show all the possible dates available (that are created in the StaffDuty models). My user should be able to just book a single date.

My problem is that I'm not able to save a single appointment, I have to compile all the form showed in my list to be able to submit. How can I solve this?

**models.py**

```
class UserAppointment(models.Model):            
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    staff = models.ForeignKey(StaffDuty, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_appointment = models.DateField(null=True)  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event.name | str(self.staff.date_work)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

**views.py**

```
class UserAppointmentAddView(CreateView):
    model = UserAppointment
    form_class = UserAppointmentForm
    template_name = "reservation.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user.userinformation
      
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['object_list'] = StaffDuty.objects.order_by('id')
        return super(UserAppointmentAddView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

**html**

```
<div class="container">
<form method="post">       
{% csrf_token %} 
{% for appointment in object_list %}                                        

      <span>{{ form.staff }}</span>
      <span>{{ form.event }}</span>
      <span>{{ form.morning_hour }}</span>
      <span>{{ form.afternoon_hour }}</span>           
      <div class="primary-btn">
      <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      </div>
</div>
     
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you are generating the same form for each appointment/  model instance, which won't work. What gets POSTed back does not identify which appointment object it refers to. That could be fixed with a hidden object_id field ... which is part of what model formsets do for you. Or you might put it into the value of your multiple submit buttons and pull it out of `request.POST` if you are happy to handle validation yourself.

The pure-Django solution is to generate a [model formset.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) When it is submitted you would process the form that has changed and ignore the rest. (It will in fact give you lists of changed and unchanged objects).

The other approach would be using JavaScript to populate one form (possibly with hidden fields) when the user clicks on values in a table. Or no form in the template, just POST from JavaScript and validate what comes back through a form (or otherwise)

Formsets and model formsets look fearsomely complicated the first time you try to use them. They aren't really, but the first one you code may present you with a bit of a steep learning curve. It's easier if you can find something working  that somebody else has already written, and adapt it.